# Build a command for article contracté in European languages

Tags: macros, strings

I would like to build a command `\contraction{<prep>}{<art>}` to do the "article contracté" in European languages. For example, I would like to have

```
\contraction{de}{le}
```

return `du` in French. Thus internally, it should do something like:

```
if #1 = prep1 and #2 = art1, return result1
if #1 = prep2 and #2 = art2, return result2
...
```

I wasn't able to come up with a simple and elegant way to achieve this: repeating things like

```
\IfStrEq{<prep>}{#1}{%
        \IfStrEq{<art>}{#2}{%
            <result>%
        }{}%
    }{}%
```

is certainly not a nice approach. Do you have any suggestions?

---

The motivation for this is to help `\cref` addressing the contraction properly. For example, with predefined `\crefname{theorem}{le théorème}{les théorème}` and `\crefname{proposition}{la proposition}{les propositions}`, when one writes

```
On peut le déduire de \cref{thm1,thm2,prop3}.
```

(which is "*We can deduce this from ...*" in French) one would get

> On peut le déduire **de les** théorèmes 1 et 2 et **la** proposition 3.

However, the correct result should be:

> On peut le déduire **des** théorèmes 1 et 2 et **de la** proposition 3.

Thus it would be better to have a new command `\ccref[<prep>]{<labels>}`, and to use it like

```
\ccref[de]{thm1,thm2,prop3}
```

in order to get

```
des théorèmes 1 et 2 et de la proposition 3.
```

For this purpose, something like `\contraction` would be needed internally.

Comment: While this can work in French, it won't in Italian where the contraction of “di” and “lo” can be either “dello” or “dell’” (with an apostrophe not followed by space) depending on the following word. And, anyway, the choice of the masculine article itself depends on the following word, so I find the project dubiously useful. And languages vary in their usage of articles.

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right, but actually I'm trying to access to the internal of `\cref`  to make it address the contraction correctly. In this case I always know what the following word is (for example "le théorème"), and by defining a new command like `\ccref[<prep>]{<labels>}`, it would be possible to automatically add the right prefix.

Comment: One possible approach is to add them to a `translator` dictionary. Note that `translator` assumes you can get by with simple word substitutions, such as, `\translate{of the}`. This will not always work. For example, the translation for “of the theorem” might have a different grammatical gender in different languages, or need to be declined differently in different cases.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** The original version cannot be nested. Here is an expl3 version.

```
\NewExpandableDocumentCommand{\contraction}{mm}{%
    \str_case_e:nn { \languagename }
    {
        {french}{%
            \str_case_e:nnF {#1~#2} {%
                {à~le}      {au}%
                {à~la}      {à~la}%
                {à~l'}      {à~l'}%
                {à~les}     {aux}%
                {de~le}     {du}%
                {de~la}     {de~la}%
                {de~l'}     {de~l'}%
                {de~les}    {des}%
            }{#2}%
        }%
        {italian}{%
            \str_case_e:nnF {#1~#2} {%
                {a~il}      {al}%
                {a~lo}      {allo}%
                {a~l'}      {all'}%
                {a~la}      {alla}%
                {di~il}     {del}%
                {di~lo}     {dello}%
                {di~l'}     {dell'}%
                {di~la}     {della}%
                {da~il}     {dal}%
                {da~lo}     {dallo}%
                {da~l'}     {dall'}%
                {da~la}     {dalla}%
                {in~il}     {nel}%
                {in~lo}     {nello}%
                {in~l'}     {nell'}%
                {in~la}     {nella}%
                {su~il}     {sul}%
                {su~lo}     {sullo}%
                {su~l'}     {sull'}%
                {su~la}     {sulla}%
                {a~i}       {ai}%
                {a~gli}     {agli}%
                {a~le}      {alle}%
                {di~i}      {dei}%
                {di~gli}    {degli}%
                {di~le}     {delle}%
                {da~i}      {dai}%
                {da~gli}    {dagli}%
                {da~le}     {dalle}%
                {in~i}      {nei}%
                {in~gli}    {negli}%
                {in~le}     {nelle}%
                {su~i}      {sui}%
                {su~gli}    {sugli}%
                {su~le}     {sulle}%
            }{#2}%
        }%
        {portuguese}{%
            \str_case_e:nnF {#1~#2} {%
                {a~o}       {ao}%
                {a~a}       {à}%
                {a~os}      {aos}%
                {a~as}      {às}%
                {de~o}      {do}%
                {de~a}      {da}%
                {de~os}     {dos}%
                {de~as}     {das}%
                {em~o}      {no}%
                {em~a}      {na}%
                {em~os}     {nos}%
                {em~as}     {nas}%
            }{#2}%
        }%
        {brazilian}{%
            \str_case_e:nnF {#1~#2} {%
                {a~o}       {ao}%
                {a~a}       {à}%
                {a~os}      {aos}%
                {a~as}      {às}%
                {de~o}      {do}%
                {de~a}      {da}%
                {de~os}     {dos}%
                {de~as}     {das}%
                {em~o}      {no}%
                {em~a}      {na}%
                {em~os}     {nos}%
                {em~as}     {nas}%
            }{#2}%
        }%
        {spanish}{%
            \str_case_e:nnF {#1~#2} {%
                {a~el}      {al}%
                {de~el}     {del}%
            }{#2}%
        }%
    }%
}
```

---

**Original post**

In the end I wrote something like this, quite similar to what @Davislor described in the comment. Since I am not familiar with these languages, please let me know if there is any mistake.

```
\usepackage{xstring}

\newcommand{\contraction}[2]{%
    \IfStrEqCase{\languagename}{%
        {french}{%
            \IfStrEqCase{#1~#2}{%
                {à~le}      {au}%
                {à~la}      {à la}%
                {à~l'}      {à l'}%
                {à~les}     {aux}%
                {de~le}     {du}%
                {de~la}     {de la}%
                {de~l'}     {de l'}%
                {de~les}    {des}%
            }[#2]%
        }%
        {italian}{%
            \IfStrEqCase{#1~#2}{%
                {a~il}      {al}%
                {a~lo}      {allo}%
                {a~l'}      {all'}%
                {a~la}      {alla}%
                {di~il}     {del}%
                {di~lo}     {dello}%
                {di~l'}     {dell'}%
                {di~la}     {della}%
                {da~il}     {dal}%
                {da~lo}     {dallo}%
                {da~l'}     {dall'}%
                {da~la}     {dalla}%
                {in~il}     {nel}%
                {in~lo}     {nello}%
                {in~l'}     {nell'}%
                {in~la}     {nella}%
                {su~il}     {sul}%
                {su~lo}     {sullo}%
                {su~l'}     {sull'}%
                {su~la}     {sulla}%
                {a~i}       {ai}%
                {a~gli}     {agli}%
                {a~le}      {alle}%
                {di~i}      {dei}%
                {di~gli}    {degli}%
                {di~le}     {delle}%
                {da~i}      {dai}%
                {da~gli}    {dagli}%
                {da~le}     {dalle}%
                {in~i}      {nei}%
                {in~gli}    {negli}%
                {in~le}     {nelle}%
                {su~i}      {sui}%
                {su~gli}    {sugli}%
                {su~le}     {sulle}%
            }[#2]%
        }%
        {portuguese}{%
            \IfStrEqCase{#1~#2}{%
                {a~o}       {ao}%
                {a~a}       {à}%
                {a~os}      {aos}%
                {a~as}      {às}%
                {de~o}      {do}%
                {de~a}      {da}%
                {de~os}     {dos}%
                {de~as}     {das}%
                {em~o}      {no}%
                {em~a}      {na}%
                {em~os}     {nos}%
                {em~as}     {nas}%
            }[#2]%
        }%
        {brazilian}{%
            \IfStrEqCase{#1~#2}{%
                {a~o}       {ao}%
                {a~a}       {à}%
                {a~os}      {aos}%
                {a~as}      {às}%
                {de~o}      {do}%
                {de~a}      {da}%
                {de~os}     {dos}%
                {de~as}     {das}%
                {em~o}      {no}%
                {em~a}      {na}%
                {em~os}     {nos}%
                {em~as}     {nas}%
            }[#2]%
        }%
        {spanish}{%
            \IfStrEqCase{#1~#2}{%
                {a~el}      {al}%
                {de~el}     {del}%
            }[#2]%
        }%
    }%
}
```